# Show that the following sequence converges to $1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a$ be a positive real number and $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of rational numbers such that

$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0 $

Show that

$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a^{x_n} = 1 $

I know that
$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a^{1/n} = 1 $

But I am struggling to adapt that to his problem

**Update**:

Thanks to the hints I have completed the proof as:

For $1>\epsilon > 0, a > 1 $

$$ |a^{x_n} - 1 | < \epsilon$$
$$ \iff 1 - \epsilon  < a^{x_n} < 1 + \epsilon $$
$$ \iff \frac{\ln(1 - \epsilon)}{\ln(a)}  < {x_n} < \frac{\ln(1 + \epsilon)}{\ln(a)} $$
$$ \iff {x_n} < \frac{\ln(1 + \epsilon)}{\ln(a)}$$
$$ \iff \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0 $$

For $1>\epsilon > 0, a < 1 $

$$ |a^{x_n} - 1 | < \epsilon$$
$$ \iff 1 - \epsilon  < a^{x_n} < 1 + \epsilon $$
$$ \iff \frac{\ln(1 + \epsilon)}{\ln(a)}  < {x_n} < \frac{\ln(1 - \epsilon)}{\ln(a)} $$
$$ \iff {x_n} < \frac{\ln(1 - \epsilon)}{\ln(a)}$$
$$ \iff \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0 $$

For the cases where $a = 1$ or $\epsilon > 1$ are trivially true

Comment: Do you know that the function $f(x) = a^x$ is continuous on real numbers?

Comment: "I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=1$"... How did you prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=1$? Maybe you can adapt that _proof_ to the problem, even though you may not be able to _use_ this fact in your proof.

Comment: Do you know the definition of limit?

Comment: @Riemann I don't know whether $f(x)=a^x$ is continuous on real numbers or not.

Comment: @StinkingBishop So the proof involves taking three cases. $(i) a = 1; (ii) a > 1; (iii) 0 < a < 1; $ The first one is trivial and in the other two, you use bernoulli's inequality to prove the other two cases. Somewhat like here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681154/proof-verification-limc1-n-1-for-c0

Comment: Seems to me that this proof is easily adaptable to your case. Let's say $a>1$ and you want $1-\epsilon<a^{x_n}<1+\epsilon$. If you are allowed to take $\log_a$ of both sides, do it - etc. etc.

Comment: For the case $0<a<1$ it suffices to consider $b=\frac1 a>1$ an then $$a^{x_n} =\left(\frac1b\right)^{x_n}=\frac1{b^{x_n} }\to 1$$

Comment: @user Yeah, I realize there are easier ways of doing it. Feels silly now that I was struggling over this. But I enjoyed the practice of doing it rigorously.

Comment: @s_a94248 Well done! Very nice work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exponential function is contínuous, you can write $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a^{x_n}$ as $a^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{x_n}}$. Solve it using the hypothesis.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could do that. I will probably learn that next! Thanks